# Center of mass and velocity of rotating object

Tags: homework-and-exercises, rotational-dynamics, rotation

[image]

I tried to solve this problem with V = R$\omega$, using $\omega$ = 2$\pi$/T and R = R - 2r (where the point opposite of contact is).  However, I am not getting the correct answers at all.  I looked at the solution and do not understand at all.

Why is the speed of the point of contact twice the speed of the COM?  Isn't the formula V = R$\omega$, so the farther away from the center, the more the tangential speed increases?

Comment: Welcome to Physics! Please [do not post images of texts you want to quote](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563), but type it out instead so it is readable for all users and so that it can be indexed by search engines. For formulae, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) instead.